# add column when calculating cumulative sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I use this query in order to fill missing gaps months when calculationg `qty_ytd`.

```
Declare @Sample Table(year int, month int, qty_ytd int);
Insert @Sample(year, month, qty_ytd) Values
(2017,   01,    20),
(2017,   02,   30),
(2018,   01,    50);

;With Months As
(Select 1 As month
Union All
Select month + 1 From Months Where month < 12),

Years As (Select Distinct year From @Sample)

Select y.year, m.month, x.qty_ytd
From Years y
Cross Join Months m
Cross Apply (Select Max(s.qty_ytd) As qty_ytd From @Sample s Where s.year = y.year And s.month <= m.month) As x 
Order By year, month;
```

[image]

How to add column QTY that contains the values of QTY_ytd in the original table ?

[image]

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: @Squirrel I update my question.

Comment: the `QTY` for `2017 / 02`  should be 10 right ?

Comment: @Squirrel I just need to get the same value as it's in the original table. So it's 30.

Comment: than that is not really `QTY` and the `ytd_qty` is not really a `YTD` figure at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @Sample Table(year int, month int, qty_ytd int);
Insert @Sample(year, month, qty_ytd) Values
(2017,   01,    20),
(2017,   02,   30),
(2018,   01,    50);

;With Months As
(Select 1 As month
Union All
Select month + 1 From Months Where month < 12)
, YearsAndMonths As
(Select distinct year,m.month from @Sample cross join Months m)

select ym.*, coalesce(s.qty_ytd, s2.qty_ytd) qty_ytd, coalesce(s.qty_ytd, 0) QTY from YearsAndMonths ym
left join @sample s on ym.year = s.year and ym.month = s.month
left join (select qty_ytd, year,
                  row_number() over (partition by year order by month desc) rn
           from @Sample) s2 on ym.year = s2.year and rn = 1
```

Comment: I am looking to get QTY and QTY_YTD in the same line.

Comment: If I add anothor column for example product, how coul I modify the query please?